# A question about a limit with two parameters

Tags: calculus, limits

Determine the values of the two real parameters $a$ and $b$ such that

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x-(ax^3+bx)}{x^3}=1$$

I immediately have thought of the Hopital theorem. We have:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x-(ax^3+bx)}{x^3}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos x-3ax^2-b}{3x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-b}{3x^2}\equiv 1$$

Now I am not able to find  $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Maturità? @Sebastiano

Comment: @Zima yes but the solutions are Just for me and not for students.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: if the limit of a fraction tends to a finite number and the denominator tends to $0$, then also the numerator must tend to zero as if not then the limit is infinite (or doesn’t exist).

Apply this after having used l’Hôpital rule to get

> $$b=1$$
>  and then apply l’Hôpital again.

---

Addendum: we want to prove that if $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)=0$ then $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ is also $0$.

Indeed by definition
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1\iff \forall \varepsilon > 0\ \exists \delta |x-x_0|<\delta_1 \implies \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-1\right|<\varepsilon$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)=0\iff \forall \varepsilon > 0\ \exists \delta |x-x_0|<\delta_2 \implies |g(x)|<\varepsilon$$

thus for $\delta = \min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-1\right|<\varepsilon&\iff |f(x)-g(x)|<\varepsilon\cdot |g(x)|\\
&\implies |f(x)|-|g(x)|<\varepsilon|g(x)|\\
&\iff |f(x)|<(\varepsilon+1)|g(x)|\\
&\iff |f(x)|<(\varepsilon+1)|\varepsilon\\
&\implies |f(x)|<2\varepsilon \tag{$\varepsilon <1$}
\end{align*}
which is by definition saying that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=0$.

Comment: +1 surely. Also I have thought your same hint. Where born the "if the limit of a fraction tends to a finite number and the denominator tends to 0, then also the numerator must tend to zero as if not then the limit is infinite (or doesn’t exist)". What is the propriety or theorem?

Comment: Where I find that: So for a fraction with denominator tending to zero, for it to have finite limit, numerator should also tend to zero?

Comment: I don't think this is a "theorem", but if you want to prove it formally then you have to  cover the remaining cases: assume that the limit is finite but non-zero, infinite and lastly that it doesn't exist and show that in all these cases the limit can't be finite.

Comment: Let me provide a proof... give me 5' to write it up.

Comment: OK 

Comment: Have a look and let me know.

Comment: Perfect proof. I never studied such a property in my university.

Comment: Glad to be of help! Cheers

Comment: I had thought that the numerator was zero because I was thinking of a straight line with the directorial numbers l, m, n. My geometry professor told us that if the denominator tends to zero, the numerator will also tend to zero. GRAZIEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

Comment: The intuition is correct, but then it's good to back it up using the definition as intuitions in limits can be misleading :)

Answer (score 4):

We can refer to this [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1337564/505767)

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}=-\frac16$$

to obtain

$$\frac{\sin x-(ax^3+bx)}{x^3}=\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}-\frac{ax^3+(b-1)x}{x^3}$$

from which we see that we need $b=1$ and $a=-\frac 76$.

Comment: Thank you very much. But how find you $b=1$ and $a=-\frac 76$?

Comment: We need that $b=1$ in such way that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ax^3+(b-1)x}{x^3}$ exists, then we need $$\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}-a \to -\frac16-a =1 \implies a=-\frac 76$$

Comment: I have understood.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano Well done! You are welcome! Bye